# In Xcode 8.3.3, swift 3, can XCUICoordinate be used without a normalized offset?

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

All of the info I could find regarding XCUICoordinate uses normalized offsets.  For example `XCUIApplication().coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0))`.  As far as I understand it, the normalized offset means it won't be a pixel value for dx/dy, but a unit based on the size of the element itself.  So `dx: 0.5, dy: 0.5` will be directly in the middle of the element and `0, 0` would be the exact top left corner.  This has caused some issues for me because using the `.screenPoint` method seems to return a pixel based coordinate and there's not an (obvious to me) way to convert it into some sort of normalized value I can use.

Is there some way to just use real pixel based coordinates or some built in way to convert them?

Comment: You know the element's `frame`, so it's trivial to convert a point in superview coordinates or internal (bounds) coordinates to a normalized offset.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `frame` method.  That's very helpful, thank you.

Comment: I'm not saying, though, that Apple couldn't have made this easier! Feel free to file an enhancement request about this impedance mismatch.